# Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain when hosted on AWS

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

website link to assist in troubleshooting: http://ec2-54-227-148-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com/architect/

I'm trying to launch Anyplace Architect on my own server.  I've gone into the google developer console and set my key & Authorized JavaScript origins to my site, but when I hit the site, I get the following:

[image]

In the developer console, I see:

```
Request URL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=listSessions&client_id=964916910124-bv0kcgd7lrbhblvc0okebbhahitnnerl.apps.googleusercontent.com&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-54-227-148-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com&scope=openid%20profile%20email&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-54-227-148-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 
Remote Address:10.15.8.202:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

When I lunch locally it works perfectly, and I don't even see that request within networking tab on the developer console in chrome.

[image]

Both localhost:5000 & the AWS site are on the approved list from google

[image]

UPDATE:

This might just be my ignorance of how the sign-in tool works, but I've been able to find out the calls for localhost and my hosted environment are different.  The localhost address goes to google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount:

```
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=964916910124-bv0kcgd7lrbhblvc0okebbhahitnnerl.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=woofRlZRVjxqKYzi0Xbttw&destination=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000&approval_state=!ChRhQmpLNEZRVHZJVEo2TW4xUHZwbhIfd3hHcnJMMDRJYlVkMEs2dFEwd1Nsa3YxeWR4ZUt4WQ%E2%88%99AB8iHBUAAAAAWs-i2_Lj-7nWLqvZjcwt3RArM0a3r6wB&xsrfsig=AHgIfE9BSG8q4mj-GBLin4PQT5-zv5fhhQ&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow
```

while the hosted goes to google.com/o/oauth2/auth

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttp%2Fec2-54-227-148-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com%3Fid%3Dauth422135&response_type=code%20permission%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20email&openid.realm=&client_id=964916910124-bv0kcgd7lrbhblvc0okebbhahitnnerl.apps.googleusercontent.com&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-54-227-148-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&prompt=consent&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fec2-54-227-148-233.compute-1.amazonaws.com&gsiwebsdk=2
```

Comment: If no one here knows the answer or is able to help, can someone post where I can go to get assistance with this? I've checked the google forms and I can't find the category for this.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem for **ec2 url**, It was working in localhost.

Here's what you can do.

1. Get IP address - (more preferably Elastic IP as ec2 IP changes with every reboot).
2. use magic domain - xip.io or nip.io
   Ex. your IP address `11.12.0.0` becomes => `http://11.12.0.0.xip.io` or `http://11.12.0.0.nip.io`
3. Use above adress in google and in your browser.

Cheers

Comment: on other answers I found the recommendation for using **xip.io** and that is what worked for me. I thought it would not be necessary, since I was using the domain version of ec2 (`http://ec2-11-12-0-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) but it seems like those don't work either